# Can't deploy properly on Vercel

Tags: vercel, astrojs

I'm using Astro to build a little portfolio. I uploaded it without problems to GitHub and also made a `npm run dev` that worked.

I also tried to deploy to Netlify and works properly.

That's what I get when deploy to Vercel (the deploy works, but I got this error):

[image]

And here is my `astro.config.mjs`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";

import vercel from "@astrojs/vercel/serverless";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind()],
  output: "server",
  adapter: vercel()
});
```

Comment: Just want to check if your site needs to be server side rendered, or could be static? Most portfolio sites are static and then you wouldn't need the adapter.